# How to keep retrying the reactive method until it succeeds?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient, system.reactive

Here is my async download reactive extension for WebClient.
What is the best way to recall "DownloadStringAsync" again and again till the operation succeeds?

Something like this but in reactive way:

```
while (true)
{
  var result = DownloadStringAsync();
  if (result)
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

---

MY CODE:

```
[Serializable]
public class WebClientException : Exception
{
    public WebClientResponse Response { get; set; }

    public WebClientException()
    {
    }

    public WebClientException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public WebClientException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected WebClientException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}

public class WebClientResponse
{
    public WebHeaderCollection Headers { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public WebException Exception { get; set; }
}

public static IObservable<WebClientResponse> DownloadStringAsync(this WebClient webClient, Uri address, WebHeaderCollection requestHeaders)
{
    var asyncResult =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>
            (ev => webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += ev, ev => webClient.DownloadStringCompleted -= ev)
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)
            .Select(o =>
                        {
                            var ex = o.EventArgs.Error as WebException;

                            if (ex == null)
                            {
                                var wc = (WebClient) o.Sender;

                                return new WebClientResponse {Headers = wc.ResponseHeaders, Result = o.EventArgs.Result};
                            }

                            var wcr = new WebClientResponse {Exception = ex};

                            var r = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                            if (r != null)
                            {
                                wcr.Headers = r.Headers;
                                wcr.StatusCode = r.StatusCode;

                                var s = r.GetResponseStream();
                                if (s != null)
                                {
                                    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(s))
                                    {
                                        wcr.Result = tr.ReadToEnd();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            throw new WebClientException {Response = wcr};
                        })
            .Take(1);

    if (requestHeaders != null)
    {
        foreach (var key in requestHeaders.AllKeys)
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add(key, requestHeaders[key]);
        }
    }

    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(address);

    return asyncResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method produces a hot observable, which means that it has already started loading when it returns and each new subscription does not create a new request to the web server. You need to wrap your method in another and use Observable.Create (in order to create a cold observable which does create a new request upon each subscription):

```
public static IObservable<WebClientResponse> DownloadStringAsync(this WebClient webClient, Uri address, WebHeaderCollection requestHeaders)
{
    return Observable
        .Create(observer => 
        {
            DownloadStringAsyncImpl(webClient, address, requestHeaders)
                .Subscribe(observer);
            return () => { webClient.CancelAsync(); };
        });
}
```

Here, DownloadStringAsyncImpl is your previous implementation of DownloadStringAsync, while the public method has been replaced.

Now you can retry the async method until it succeeds as follows:

```
myWebClient
    .DownloadStringAsync( /* args... */)
    .Retry()
    .Subscribe(result => { 
         /* now I've got a result! */
    });
```

Comment: A more straightforward way is to just use Observable.Defer()

Comment: oops, i've already made defer implementation myself but i didn't realize it, because i was getting just one output to console after Retry(3). My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have at least one decent "here is some code" answer, so I will focus on a more general hand holding.

The first thing I would look at is the [design guidelines for Rx](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219). It is a short (34 page) PDF document that helps change paradigm from pull "subscriptions" to push, or moving from IEnumerable to IObservable.

If you want to go a bit further, there are PDF HOLs (hands on labs) for both [.NET](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208528) and [JavaScript](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208527). You can find other resources on the Rx pages ([start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)).

Answer (score 0):

If it is an async function. Doing a repetitive checking means you turned it into a sync function call. Is this something you really want to do?

You can have a dedicated thread calling this async function and block itself after calling this function. When create this thread, pass it a delegate that should be called after the async function returns. Upon completion, call the delegate with error code.

Hope this answers your question.